# How can these two Feynman-Kac formulas be equivalent?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, mathematical-physics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), the Feynman-Kac formula allows one to map

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) = 0$

onto SDEs of the form

$dX = \mu(X,t)\,dt + \sigma(X,t)\,dW$.

However, according to e.g. [eq. (38) in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.6500.pdf), the relevant Fokker-Planck equation would rather correspond to

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\mu(x,t) u(x,t)\right] + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\left[\sigma^2(x,t)u(x,t) \right] = 0$.

How can they both  be correct?

Comment: One is forward and one is backward.

Comment: @user658409 can you be more explicit? I don't see it

Comment: Google "Kolmogorov forward and backward equation"

Comment: @user658409 thanks, that solves my question. If you upgrade your comment to an answer, I'll accept. If not, I'll add one myself.